# Indexes for more than one column in DB

Tags: oracle11g, indexing

I am new to idexes and DB optimization. I know there is simple index for one

```
CREATE index ON table(col)
```

possibly B-Tree will be created and search capabilities will be improved.

But what is happen for 2 columns index ? And why is the order of defnition important?

```
CREATE index ON table(col1, col2)
```

Comment: Does [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28271_01/server.1111/e25789/indexiot.htm#sthref285) answer your question?

Comment: http://use-the-index-luke.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, B-Tree index will be created in most of the database if you didn't specify other type of index. Composite index is useful when the combined selectivity of the composite columns happed on the queries.

The order of the columns on the composite index is important as searching by giving exact values for all the fields included in the index leads to minimal search time but search uses only the first field to retrieve all matched recaords if we provide the values partially with first field.

**I found following example for your understanding:**

In the phone book example with an composite index created on the columns (city, last_name, first_name), if we search by giving exact values for all the three fields, search time is minimal—but if we provide the values for city and first_name only, the search uses only the city field to retrieve all matched records. Then a sequential lookup checks the matching with first_name. So, to improve the performance, one must ensure that the index is created on the order of search columns.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My question was too broad.